# How do I display subtotals in cube browser in SSAS 2012 (Sql Server Data Tools)?

Tags: ssas, sql-server-2012, business-intelligence, cube, olap-cube

Apparently this feature was available in previous versions but has now been removed.

What are some alternatives?

Comment: It belongs to http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Browse the cube using excel or powerpivot. There you can manipulate it a bit better.